# What causes a 400 Bad Request error for null ("") and why would our nginx logs have so many?

Tags: linux, web-server, nginx, ruby-on-rails, web-applications

Daily logs from Logwatch regularly report 400 Bad Request, null: 1744 Time(s) from our nginx logs.

The log entries look like:

`123.123.123.123 - - [25/Jan/2011:14:44:19 -0500] "-" 400 173 "-" "-"`

Can anyone explain how these are generated and why there are so many?  It doesn't appear to be hurting anything, but we've had  up to 8000 appear in a day.  We host a medium size rails application running on unicorn and nginx.

There is [some discussion](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,9695,11560) in the nginx forum, but I haven't found a real solution that decreases the number for 400 Bad Reqeusts logged.

Comment: What are the IP addresses making the bad requests? As it says in the thread, it may be a monitoring program that only opens a TCP connection.

Comment: There are many IP addresses.  Most have a session that includes normal web traffic mixed with these 400's.  I think I've only witnessed the activity from IE browsers in samples where I've zeroed in on a session's worth of traffic.

Comment: I've noticed on my server that using Firefox to access a page always gives one of these blank 400 logs exactly 5 seconds after the last valid request, while Firebug shows no errors. This lends credence to @Avleen's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This often happens when a browser is using Keep-Alive and reaches the keep alive timeout.
It's quite normal.

If you see 400 errors with a URI / path / method such as GET or POST, etc, then you have a legitimate problem with a user making a bad request. But those should be rare.

Comment: In my case no http method, just null for requests and null user-gents